# Selecting elements of two column whose difference is less than some given value using awk

Tags: awk, comparison

While doing post processing for a numerical analysis, I have the following problem of selection of data :

```
time_1     result_1              time_2       result_2
1          10                    1.1          10.1
2          20                    1.6          15.1
3          30                    2.1          20.1
4          40                    2.6          25.1
5          50                    3.1          30.1
6          60                    3.6          35.1
7          70                    4.1          40.1
8          80                    4.6          45.1
9          90                    5.1          50.1
10         100                   5.6          55.1
                                 6.1          60.1
                                 6.6          65.1
                                 7.1          70.1
                                 7.6          75.1
                                 8.1          80.1
                                 8.6          85.1
                                 9.1          90.1
                                 9.6          95.1
                                 10.1         100.1
```

This file has 4 columns, the first column (time_1) represents the calculated instants of a program 1, the second column (result_1) is the results calculated for each instant.

The third column (time_2) represents represents the calculated instants of another program, the fourth column (result_2) is the results calculated for each instant of this program 2.

Now I wish to select only the instants of the third column (time_2) that is very near the instants of the first column (time_1), the difference admitted is less than or equal to 0.1. For example :

for the instant 1 of the time_1 column, I wish to select the instant 1.1 of the time_2 column, because (1.1 - 1) = 0.1, I do not want to select the others instants of the time_2 column because (1.6 - 1) > 0.1, or (2.1 - 1) > 0.1

for the instant 2 of the time_1 column, I wish to select the instant 2.1 of the time_2 column, because (2.1 - 2) = 0.1, I do not want to select the others instants of the time_2 column because (2.6 - 1) > 0.1, or (3.1 - 1) > 0.1

At the end, I would like to obtain the following data :

```
time_1     result_1              time_2       result_2
1          10                    1.1          10.1
2          20                    2.1          20.1
3          30                    3.1          30.1
4          40                    4.1          40.1
5          50                    5.1          50.1
6          60                    6.1          60.1
7          70                    7.1          70.1
8          80                    8.1          80.1
9          90                    9.1          90.1
10         100                   10.1         100.1
```

I wish to use awk but I have not been familiarized with this code. I do not know how to fix an element of the first column then compare this to all elements of the third column in order to select the right value of this third column. If I do very simply like this, I can print only the first line :

```
{if (($3>=$1) && (($3-$1) <= 0.1)) {print  $2, $4}}
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Will there be exactly one relevant instant in column 3 for each value in column 1? Or can there be many candidates in column 3, for a given value in column 1?

Comment: I guess it would be easier to extract and format the data if column 1 and 2, where in one file, and column 3 and 4 in another file.. (since the column lengths seems to be different, and this makes it more cumbersome to handle for `awk` and other text processing tools)

Comment: effectively, although in this example there is only one element of 3rd column satifying the selection criterion, I would like be able to identify somes elements of column 3 for each given element of column 1

Comment: I think of using the array to stock then manipulate easier the data but I have not yet succeeded

Comment: Will the number of items in column 1 always be smaller or equal to the number of items in column 3? (In this way, the program can know in the case there are only two items on a line, that they will belong to column 3 and 4, and not column 1 and 2)

Comment: Are the values in column 1 and 3 always sorted? (In increasing order, that is: smallest values first)

Comment: Yes, the values in columns 1 and 3 are always sorted. It is also confirmed that the number of items in column 1 is always smaller or equal to the number of items in column 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to be aware of: due to the vagaries of floating point numbers, comparing a value to 0.1 is unlikely to give you the results you're looking for:

```
awk 'BEGIN {x=1; y=x+0.1; printf "%.20f", y-x}'
0.10000000000000008882⏎
```

here, `y=x+0.1`, but `y-x > 0.1`

So, we will look at the diff as `diff = 10*y - 10x`:

Also, I'm going to process the file twice: once to grab all the time_1/result_1 values, the second time to extract the "matching" time_2/result_2 values.

```
awk '
    NR==1   {print; next} 
    NR==FNR {if (NF==4) r1[$1]=$2; next} 
    FNR==1  {next}
    {
        if (NF == 4) {t2=$3; r2=$4} else {t2=$1; r2=$2}
        for (t1 in r1) {
            diff = 10*t1 - 10*t2; 
            if (-1 <= diff && diff <= 1) {
                print t1, r1[t1], t2, r2
                break
            }
        }
    }

' ~/tmp/timings.txt ~/tmp/timings.txt | column -t
```

```
time_1  result_1  time_2  result_2
1       10        1.1     10.1
2       20        2.1     20.1
3       30        3.1     30.1
4       40        4.1     40.1
5       50        5.1     50.1
6       60        6.1     60.1
7       70        7.1     70.1
8       80        8.1     80.1
9       90        9.1     90.1
10      100       10.1    100.1
```

Comment: I cannot do run the program from the second commande line. It is always print only the first line of the data file, that means only the command line 'NR==1   {print; next}' is taken into account. If I remove this one, the is no result line. Could you please explain me why and how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: I could do it, just because I run 'awk -f ...' but I forgot processing the file twice as you adviced.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);

my @lines=read_file("file");

shift @lines; # skip first line

my @a;

for (@lines) {
    my @fld=split;
    if (@fld == 4) {
        push (@a,{id=>$fld[0], val=>$fld[1]});
    }
}

for (@lines) {
    my @fld=split;
    my $id; my $val;
    if (@fld == 4) {
        $id=$fld[2]; $val=$fld[3];
    } elsif (@fld == 2) {
        $id=$fld[0]; $val=$fld[1];
    }
    my $ind=checkId(\@a,$id);
    if ($ind>=0) {
        $a[$ind]->{sel}=[] if (! exists($a[$ind]->{sel}));
        push(@{$a[$ind]->{sel}},{id=>$id,val=>$val});
    }
}

for my $item (@a) {
    if (exists $item->{sel}) {
        my $s= $item->{sel};
        for (@$s) {
            print $item->{id}."\t".$item->{val}."\t";
            print $_->{id}."\t".$_->{val}."\n";
        }
    }
}


sub checkId { 
    my ($a,$id) = @_;

    my $dif=0.1+1e-10;

    for (my $i=0; $i<=$#$a; $i++) {
        return $i if (abs($a->[$i]->{id}-$id)<=$dif)
    }
    return -1;
}
```